AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_signal_handlers' while running pytest
This is my error:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 233.15026.15)
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x12809be50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 688, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 60, in close
    for sig in list(self._signal_handlers):
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_signal_handlers'
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x12809be50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 688, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 60, in close
    for sig in list(self._signal_handlers):
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_signal_handlers'
Launching pytest with arguments <args here>


I am getting above error as soon as I launch purest. I'm using PyCharm on Mac M1. I am not sure what further information to provide. If you need any more information, please let me know in the comment. This is all the stacktrace that I see.
Any help will be appreciated.

What version of python are you using?

I am using 3.9.19

Hmm, Try using 3.12.2,  I had the same issue some weeks ago and i updated python and pycharm and it worked, let me know if something is missing in my answer since i saw a downvote on it

cannot upgrade, must be on 3.9.19 - since I've dependencies on other packages that won't work.
